# NSOperation and NSOperationQueue does not work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have the following code and it does not work. Is there something working behind it.

```
[operationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
        imageData =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            UIImage *image = nil;

            if(imageData){
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                cell.imageView.image = image;
            }
        }];
    }];
```

Even I create a subclass of NSOperation and then alloc init it, it does not work the way I think it to. I always have to invoke start to the NSOperation subclass to run but I suppose sending start message to NSOperation runs it in the main thread rather than running in the background thread.

Comment: What is the output? IF you want help, tell us what error was triggered. We are not mind-readers.

Comment: Have you tried putting breakpoints at the lines `imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];` and `UIImage *image = nil;`?  Knowing this will allow us to know whether your program is ever executing the blocks which you've added to the two different `NSOperationQueue`s.  If you do break at `UIImage *image = nil;`, please print `[imageData length]`.

Comment: This does not work with me, I could not load image this way. I have empty response and it seems that the block for downloading the image is not being called at all.

Comment: @koyla  If `dataWithContentsOfURL:` returns `nil`, then there is something amiss with your URL.  If, on the other hand, after setting your breakpoint, you never break at the line `imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];`, then there is something wrong with your `operationQueue`.  How is it initialized?

Comment: I am not really sure the whole context, but it seem you are trying to do a `cell.imageView.image` inside a queue (which runs on another thread). Only the main thread is allowed to make changes to the UI. You may want to call a `@selector` and perform that on the main thread and then set the image

Comment: FYI, `NSOperationQueue` is not thread safe. Look at this post for explanation on thread safe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597832/thread-safety-nsoperationqueue-array-addobject

Comment: @Steven he is running that UI operation on [NSOperationQueue mainQueue], so that should be OK.

Comment: What is 'operationQueue'. Has it been init'd properly - it's not null, right?

Comment: operationQueue is simple a property which is initialized inside viewDidLoad method as;
self.operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
And then I keep on adding the operation to this instance, is there something wrong with this approach ?

Comment: operationQueue is simple a property which is initialized inside viewDidLoad method as;
self.operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to add an alternative solution using GCD :

```
backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.razeware.imagegrabber.bgqueue", NULL);
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
                          /* put the codes which makes UI unresponsive like reading from network*/ 
                         imageData =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
                         .....   ;
                         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                                         /* do the UI related work on main thread */
                                         UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                                         cell.imageView.image = image;
                                         ......;   });
                                  });
dispatch_release(backgroundQueue);
```

Let me know whether this one helped you ;)

[Reference](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial)

Comment: Hard to decide which implementation looks cleaner. I like both. The downside with this one is the need to remember dispatch_release().